# my raspberry pi 2, dont connect to Rii i8 wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am learning Linux and I am running RPi2 headless (using tightvnc) and 2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy.img installed on a 4GB Micro SD card, since
23-feb 2016. Recently I got this (http://www.riitek.com/product/i8x.html#highlights) Wireless keyboard/touchpad but it failed to work/operate, though it works fine on my windows 8 tablet. The following is a little detail of lsusb and dmesg (pastebin). It is recognized as Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0e8f:2519 GreenAsia Inc. but still don't work. will greatly appreciate any help please.

http://pastebin.com/dA4VLx6D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am just answering my own question. In fact it is the "TightVNC" that is hindering me, see the keyboard/Touch-pad working, as I said this Raspberry Pi 2 is headless.
   I connected a VGA monitor (through a HDMI to VGA adapter cable) to the HDMI port of RPi-2 and the Rii I8 keyboard is working normal (like a charm). So for all those who are using TightVNC (I haven't used any other remote admn. tool other than TightVNC), You are out of luck, until You connect and use the HDMI port of RPi-2 for viewing whatever You are doing on your "Rii i8x" wireless keyboard/touch-pad. Thanks and GOOD LUCK.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.